# Number format Exception in Java after inputting a string

Tags: java, numberformatexception

I have input a character array and now I am inputting a number from the user. At this point I am getting a NumberFormatException
My code is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    char c[] = new char[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        c[i] = (char) br.read();
    }

    int k = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

}
```

At the last line it's giving me the error.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: Are you really passing a number where you're doing `parseInt(..)`?

Comment: It would help if you would paste your input, so we can see how it is formatted

Answer (score 0):

You get a `NumberFormatException` if you try to convert a non-valid integer string or an empty string to a `Integer`.

```
String x = "abcd";

int y = Integer.parseInt(x);//this raises the exception as abcd is not a valid number
```

#### How do I handle it?

**Non-technical solution:**

Try to be a smart man and enter numbers only.

**Technical Solution:**

```
try
{
 String x = "abcd";

 int y = Integer.parseInt(x);
}
catch(NumberFormatExcpetion ne)
{

 System.out.println("Numbers Only!");
 }
```

Do not use `br.read()` to read characters. If you enter them in seperate lines it doesn't consider them.

Using `System.in.read()` instead.

```
int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
char c[] = new char[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    char ch;
    do {
        ch = (char) System.in.read();
        } while (ch != '\n');
    c[i] = ch;
    }

int k = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:504)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
 at Solution.main(Solution.java:20)

This is the error I am getting

Comment: Your input string is empty. And hence the excpetion

Comment: BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
       
        int n=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        char c[]=new char[n];
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
    c[i]=(char)System.in.read();
   
}
        System.out.println();
        int k=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());


I have done this .....and still its giving me the error

Comment: Here `enter` is also considered a character.  Please try the code which I used.